# Exclude Email Addresses from Web Address Regex

Tags: javascript, regex

Okay, I have two Regex patterns.

1. `([a-zA-Z0-9]?http[s]?:\/\/)?((?:(?:\w+)\.)(?:\S+)(?:\.(?:\w+))+?)`
2. `[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+.[a-zA-Z]{2,6}`

The first meets my needs at finding web addresses in a string. The second meets my needs at locating email addresses in a string. However, for some reason the first one is finding email addresses that look like this `first.last@d1.d2.d3.d4` or `first.last@d1.com`. I need some help getting that first one so that it doesn't pick up those email addresses.

Comment: What's wrong with it matching `first.last@d1.d2.d3.d4` or `first.last@d1.com`? They look like valid email address' to me?

Comment: @Robbie, first regex should not match those matches

Comment: The problem is that I have to issue two different types of replace statements so that I can turn those matched values into links. The first one is meant to find web addresses - so when I build an HREF I prefix the value with an `http://` but in contrast when I match the email addresses I have to prefix a `mailto:`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
([a-zA-Z0-9]?http[s]?:\/\/)?((?:(?:\w+)\.)(?:\S+)(?:\.(?:\w+))+?)
```

Breaking this down, there are several problems...

```
(             // capture protocol
[a-zA-Z0-9]?  // matches alphanumeric, optionally (do you really want that to start the string before the protoco?)
http[s]?      // square brackets delimit character class, so are unneccessary here, although don't change functionality
:\/\/         // matches ://
)?            // make captured protocol optional
((?:(?:\w+)\.)(?:\S+)(?:\.(?:\w+))+?) // too many lookaheads, not enough patterns. Innefficient and causing your error
```

I would replace the regex with something more like this...

```
(https?:\/\/)?(\w[-\w\.]+)+(:\d+)?(/([\w/_\.]*(\?\S+)?)?)?
```

Comment: Looks like I forgot to add my comments too, fixed it all now how I think it should be.

Answer (score 3):

For example you could fix it by excluding @

([a-zA-Z0-9]?http[s]?:\/\/)?((?:(?:\w+)\.)(?:**[^\s@]**+)(?:\.(?:\w+))*?)

and at the very end I suggest use *? instead of +?, +? didn't matched 1st level domain without **www**

yet it find abc@**gmail.com**

Sadly I have no idea how to check that 1st symbol before matched substring is not @

**edit**: bad solution
**^[^@]*?**([a-zA-Z0-9]?http[s]?:\/\/)?((?:(?:\w+)\.)(?:[^\s@]+)(?:\.(?:\w+))*?)
checks that there is no @s from the start of the line till matched part

Comment: are you saying that the last Regex is more correct than the first with the **edit**?

Comment: the last one checks that all symbols from the start of the line ^ are not '@', If we try to check only one symbol that would cause regex to match 'mail.com'

Comment: Pretty much works for me for excluding a set within the non capturing group (?:[\s@]+). Upvoted